# OPCUA PubSub MQTT ClientID

Tags: publish-subscribe, opc-ua, mqttnet

I'm using the OPCUA UA-.NETStandard-1.4.372.56 libraries to test PubSub components and include it in my client that already has been working for years. I tested and understood the logic behind PubSUb concepts and i wanted to split all necessaries actions needed to publish or subscribe in my Client UI, starting from the connection and going on. but I'm facing with a problem that I'm not able to setup the a new ClientID.
I read the Doc on GitHub where they say that for version 3.1.1 the property ClientID can only be set through the connectionparameters with the syntax: Name=connection-.

I've tried to set the parameters like described but it's simple dropped.
I've tried:

```
        KeyValuePair[] cps = new KeyValuePair[1];
        
        cps[0] = new KeyValuePair()
        {
            Key = new QualifiedName("Connection-ClientID", 0),
            Value = new Variant("DESKTOPOHL6LEFOPCUASimulationServer")
        };
```

I've also tried changing the parameter Name but nothing happens.

I've tried to set it up through the groupParameters or WriterParameters but it will be dropped.

I've tried to change the MQTT version but nothing.
I don't know whether I'm doing something wrong or there is some limitations for the moment.

thank you in advance for your help